# Sharepoint 2013: New Users unble to add/edit pages

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, template

We are running into an issue where some users (mostly all new users within the past 3-6 months) are unable to add/edit sharepoint pages consistently. They appear to have all the proper permissions to the page to edit (some even have full control), but when they attempt to add/edit Pages (not Wiki pages or application pages) they receive an error message saying that they don't have permission to access the page.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the page template permission, but not sure where to look to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Check if publishing feature is started at site and site collection level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue while working in one of the project. To resolve this, we did the following :

1. Go to **Site Settings**.
2. Click on **Master pages and page layouts** under **Web Designer Galleries**.
3. Click on **Library settings** from top ribbon.
4. Click on **Permissions for this document library** under **Permissions and Management**.
5. Check permissions for those particular users, if they have none permission then provide them **Read** and Ask them to try editing page now.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yup - this is exactly what I did to resolve the issue. Thank